# How to use Javascript to add HTML code without it converting escaped characters?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, innerhtml

I am using AJAX to handle a form submission. The AJAX request returns a javascript script with text string arguments. I run into a problem when I try to add the AJAX returned script to the existing page.

Here are the different things I've tried to accomplish this already:

```
newAjaxBlock.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ajaxRequest.responseText));
newAjaxBlock.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
newAjaxBlock.textContent = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

The problem is that if I use .innerHTML to insert the returned script, it converts the escaped characters in the argument text string to their HTML equivalent and the script will throw errors because of single quotes and other characters in the string.

I expected .innerHTML to take the text and write it exactly as PHP provides it without unexpected conversions from escaped characters to their HTML equivalents.

For example I would generate a script in PHP and run it through htmlspecialchars() and make a text string exactly as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='layerScript'>Lib.alertFunction(arg1, $arg2, '<p>You changed THING from &quot;value1&quot; to &quot;newValue&quot;.</p>');</script>
```

But instead .innerHTML converts it to this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='layerScript'>Lib.alertFunction(arg1, $arg2, '<p>You changed THING from "value1" to "newValue".</p>');</script>
```

and as you can see, the script won't work with single quotes and other characters messing up the argument list.

In contrast, when I tried using the createTextNode or .textContent options it creates a text node that ignores the HTML tags and shows it ALL as text instead of interpreting the HTML. This is not a surprise to me but leaves me with no option that actually just puts the HTML code in as it's written without converting the escaped characters.

All of the code works exactly as I expect and need it to except when the script argument contains single quotes or lt and gt symbols so I know I have narrowed the problem down to this single issue. I don't want jquery suggestions and I know I could code for an extra few days to make a function that does what I need but I want to know if there's something that does what .innerHTML does without converting escaped characters before I waste that time.

This exact question was already asked and was answered with "use .textContent" which as I mentioned doesn't work to insert formatted HTML with AJAX.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is with the normal "unescaped" characters. Also, I think that most browser engines automatically converts escaped chars (not only the ones introduced through javascript), because it's what they are supposed to do. You could try and check the source (not through webtools, but display source) to see if they are escaped or not (they are automatically converted in webtools too)